# Super OnActivityResult not calling Fragment OnActivityResult

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin Studio for my app. I'm having an issue similar to [this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment). I'm calling `StartActivityForResult` with an intent that launches the camera. The camera takes the picture and returns to the application just fine, and the main activity's `OnActivityResult` is called. My issue is that, despite a call to `base.OnActivityResult`, my fragment's `OnActivityResult` is never hit.

I've looked through the solutions here on SO, which are generally:

1. Call `base.StartActivityForResult` instead of `StartActivityForResult` inside the fragment
2. Call `base.OnActivityResult` in the main activity's `OnActivityResult` to forward on unhandled request codes
3. Ensure `launchMode` in the manifest is not set to `single`

Code:
Fragment -

```
void AddImage(object sender, EventArgs e){

    //Preparing intent here...

    StartActivityForResult (intent, 0);
}

//no override keyword because I'm given a compiler error stating
//that there is no OnActivityResult to override
protected void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data){
    //I call resultCode.GetHashCode here because I'm using SupportFragment
    base.OnActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode.GetHashCode(), data);

    if (resultCode == Result.Canceled)
        return;

    //process image...
}
```

Main Activity -

```
protected override void OnActivityResult (int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //processing data from other intents at the main activity level
}
```

Comment: what does your fragment class declaration look like?

Comment: My fragment inherits directly from SupportFragment, I don't have any relevant members other than an instance of the parent Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

within a SupportFragment, you should use

```
public override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    base.OnActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

instead of

```
public override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data) {
```

note the type of the arg resultCode, as a int, it'll be available to override

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks! I overlooked my use of `protected`, turns out it was giving me an error that I had misinterpreted as inappropriate use of `override`. Changing my method from `protected` to `public` and passing the proper type for `resultCode` fixed everything.

Comment: you probably also copy-pasted the `OnActivityResult` from your Activity, right ?

Comment: I don't think I did -- I'd completely forgotten I ran `StartActivityForResult` in the main activity